# QGIS 1.8 Project in 2.0.1 Bad Layers

Tags: qgis, ordnance-survey

I have a confusing problem with a project generated in QGIS 1.8 when trying to open this on a new windows pc with Darfour (same OS, Win7) The hard drive including the project has been moved from old machine to new and as such no paths etc should have changed.

[http://picpaste.com/qgisBadLayers.jpg http://picpaste.com/extpics/qgisBadLayers.jpg](http://picpaste.com/extpics/qgisBadLayers.jpg)

http://picpaste.com/qgisBadLayers.jpg

I'd obviously rather not have to manually correct all 40, and want to understand exactly what has changed / what the issue is. The layers are UK OS data.

Many thanks

---

Many thanks for your reply. The data in this case are in shapefiles from the OS Digimap service

The issue was that Darfour expects the following

```
<datasource>./OS VectorMap District (Vector)SU/data/SU/SU_AdministrativeBoundary.shp</datasource>
```

and the original project are formatted thusly:

```
<datasource>./OS VectorMap District (Vector) SU/data/SU|layername=SU_Airport</datasource>
```

a couple of quick find and replace to take the layername out and add .shp did the trick

Comment: I wonder where you got the strange datasource entries from. My QGIS Lisboa wrote the usual path/file.shp as Dufour does.

Comment: That is strange then. From what I remember these were imported using the menus in the previous version (rather than in any sort of batch or external tool)

Comment: Maybe importing a whole directory instead of single shapefiles.

Comment: Ah that could well be it, the shapefiles make up the whole digimap offering for the area (boundaries, groundwater, roads, airports etc etc)

Comment: Just tested: Both versions use the same syntax for directory input, and Lisboa saved projects open in Dufour without problems. BUT: There is a blank missing after `(Vector)` in your first line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what type of datasource your layers are from.

Shapefiles and spatialite databases are OK from one version to another, but import-only datasources like GPX might cause problems.

This might be a workaround:

Open a new project, add one of the layers to it, and compare old and new project file with a good text editor like notepad++.

Especially the `<datasource>` tags should give you a hint how the file access has changed.

After having found the difference, it should be rather easy to change all layers with `search and replace` inside the text editor. It can even be used across several opened text files at once.